# Why not using javascript Self Executed Function instead of Using jQuery's

Tags: jquery

I am currently learning jQuery and following many tutorials, almost all of them are using (function(){}(); instead of (function($){}(jQuery); I know the purpose of them are to not create a global var.  The thing is I notice I can still use jQuery object inside javascript self executed function, but I can't use them the other way. So why should I use jQuery's self exe func at all?

Comment: is not for "not create a global var" but for not "use" a global var.

Comment: Creating global variables is unavoidable. `$` (i.e. `jQuery`) is one, for example. The point is to create *as few as possible* and then only those that truly are of global usefulness - like library variables. (And even jQuery has `.noConflict()` because its `$` shorthand might clash with other libraries.)

Answer (score 1):

The premise: is simple comfortable to use `$` instead of `jQuery`.

So `$` is a simple shortcut of more verbose `jQuery`.

However `$` is used also for other libraries or it could be used also as simple variable in other part of the project.
This is a trick in order to have the certainty of using the `$` as `jQuery`, because the [scope chain rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Name_conflicts) force javascript to take first the value of variable inside your scope, and only if there isn't take the value of the global scope.

Example:

```
// jQuery is loaded
console.log($ === jQuery) // true

window.$ = {thisIs:"myObject"};

console.log($ === jQuery); // false

(function($) {
    console.log($ === jQuery); // true
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BmkYt/1/